# How to share a mounted drive in ubuntu?

Tags: mount, nautilus, samba

I installed Samba on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and since I running it off USB stick - was able to share the "Downloads" folder on my local network. However, if I try to share a folder on any mounted drive (FAT, or NTFS, Internal or External USB), I get the same warning:

> "Nautilus needs to add some permissions to your folder "the_break" in
>   order to share it"
>
> "The folder "the_break" needs the following extra permissions for
>   sharing to work:
>     - read permission by others
>     - write permission by others
>     - execute permission by others Do you want Nautilus to add these permissions to the folder automatically?"

Hitting "Add permissions automatically" closes that dialog, and I can see the share, but cannot access any files in it.
Mounting manually as described in https://superuser.com/questions/161649/sharing-a-folder-with-nautilus-and-ntfs-external-drive-gets-errors did not seem to work, or I did it wrong for my enviroment ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't share folders through Nautilus any more...  Use the samba server itself and its configuration tools to share anything.

Go to the software center, click on the search and type "samba GUI" and click on the pretty icon that you don't have to pay for, then click install and use that to share drives...

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, turning it into beautiful green and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: I tried a couple of Ubuntu samba GUI tools, they seem to have updated samba configs in ways incompatible between each other (errors on startup about config entries they don't understand), so now even the shares I had working before - are not accessible from my android app.

Comment: You did try `system-config-samba`, and it didn't solve your problem, right?  Then we'll need to dig down into the bowels of samba.  Can you edit your question and post the output of samba.conf?

Comment: system-config-samba is what I tried, yeah. I'll update the question when I have a chance to log into that machine again (the problem might also be with my app that's trying to use a share)

Comment: Just leave a comment here when you update your question, because after a couple of days with so many drive-by questions, I can't keep track any more...